# a && b && c VS if - What's the difference on performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Just saw a line of code: `a && b && c`. I think this should be equivalent to `if(a && b) {c}`. But I'm really curious that is there any performance difference on these code, or it's just simply cool to put it in one line?

This is actual code: `sourcesPanel && sourcesPanel.tips && sourcesPanel.tips.clearTimers()`

The `sourcesPanel` and `sourcesPanel.tips` are two objects in the program.
Basically, I think it's checking if those two objects exist, it they exist, call that `clearTimers` function.

Comment: Where did you see it? Depends on the context.

Comment: if it was like `if(a && b && c)` then it means if all conditions are true then execute the next statement.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf No it's not in if, just the line stand alone.

Answer (score 3):

The logical operators in JS have a very important behavior: they return the first conclusively failing or succeeding operand. If does not.

The behavior of `if (a) { if (b) { ...` is pretty simple: if they are truthy, enter the block.

The behavior of `&&` is different:

```
foo = 1 && 2 && 3; // foo = 3, succeeds all the way through
foo = 1 && 0 && 3; // foo = 0, failed at 0
foo = 1 && null && 3; // foo = null, failed at null
```

When the logical operators are used *within* an `if`, the behavior appears to be exactly the same. Used on their own or with an assignment, they behave in a relatively unexpected way.

Take the use of `||` to provide defaults:

```
opt = opt || {foo: bar};
```

If `opt` was truthy (for an object, present) use it, otherwise use the defaults. The other logical operators behave the same way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this, but I really want to know if it has performance differences when using if statement.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually a double check and not a simple conditional check like you sugest: `if(a && b) {c}`.

The equivalent to `a && b && c` would be:

```
if (a && b){
    if(c){
        // do something
```

So all `a`, `b` and `c` have to be truthy.

`a && b && c` is mostly more practical than doing

```
if (a){
    if (b){
        if(c){
            // do something
```

But in a triple check like `a && b && c` `b` will never be evaluated if `a` evaluates `false`. Thus sparing time. The same for `c` that will only be evaluated if `a` and `b` also were true.

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance improvement in some circumstances.

The line is executed step by step from left to right, and leaves as soon as it fails.

So, if a is false, b and c will not be evaluated.

You see this a lot in bash where one instruction is dependent upon another succeeding, but the first has to be attempted no matter what.

Comment: ...which is equivalent to OP's alternative. The final if statement would not be executed either.

Comment: But if I change them to nested if, it could be the same. Then why should I use the logical operators?

Comment: It's really a matter of style, I guess. Programming languages often have arbitrary user patterns that form a sort of "vernacular."